# OpenCV multi-threading capture from multiple cameras

Tags: python, opencv

I'm working on a security project for multi-threaded capture with OpenCV4 (python3) and multiple cameras. Each camera (frames) processed individually for object detection and finally stream them to the web. 
Since python has no "case" and I'm doing it this way, is it the right way to do it or what is the optimized way to do it?

```
<code>
# this is the start function
def start_cams():
    ...
    # get list of active cams
    cam_active = get_camera()  # i.e. 4 cameras
    for i in range(len(cam_active)):
        t = threading.Thread(target=process_cam, name=cam_active[i],
                             args=(cam_active[i],))
        t.daemon = True
        t.start()

# this is the capture and process function
def process_cam(cam_id):
    global lock, vs_cam_1, vs_cam_2, vs_cam_3, vs_cam_4
    global out_1, out_2, out_3, out_4
    ...
    if cam_id == "cam_4":
        vs_cam_4 = VideoProc(source=cam_src, backend=cv2.CAP_FFMPEG).start()
    elif cam_id == "cam_3":
        vs_cam_3 = VideoProc(source=cam_src, backend=cv2.CAP_FFMPEG).start()
    elif cam_id == "cam_2":
        vs_cam_2 = VideoProc(source=cam_src, backend=cv2.CAP_FFMPEG).start()
    elif cam_id == "cam_1":
        vs_cam_1 = VideoProc(source=cam_src, backend=cv2.CAP_FFMPEG).start()
   ...
   # object detection code here
   ...
    with lock:
        if cam_id == "cam_4":
            out_4 = frame.copy()
        elif cam_id == "cam_3":
            out_3 = frame.copy()
        elif cam_id == "cam_2":
            out_2 = frame.copy()
        elif cam_id == "cam_1":
            out_1 = frame.copy()

# this is the output stream function
def generate_stream(cam_id):
    global lock, out_1, out_2, out_3, out_4
    while True:
        with lock:
            if cam_id == "cam_1":
                ...
                # encode the frame in JPEG format
                (flag, encodedFrame) = cv2.imencode(".jpg", out_1)
    ...
    yield(b'--frame\r\n' b'Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n' + \
          bytearray(encodedFrame) + b'\r\n')
</code>
```

Comment: Seeing `vs_cam_1, vs_cam_2, vs_cam_3, ...` and the same code copied around 4 times... no that's definitely not the right way to do it.

Comment: Thank you pal, you're right. Actually I need to process all the cams realtime. Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: I need to use multiple cameras and process them individually.  Please suggest a better idea.